# Making a window transparent to mouse events

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, deskband

Is there any way to make an application window "transparent" for mouse events? I want my form to be visible, but it covers some elements that must be clicked. I was thinking about DeskBand, but I was told it was going to be rather difficult...

Any ideas?
Greetings!

Comment: Not sure what your question is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should go the other way around: besides thinking that it's a strange behaviour, I think it may be easier to display your form *below* elements that need to be clicked, and make these elements layer semi-transparent.